# Touchscreen not seen after installing Ubuntu 23.10 on HP Envy x360 - 13-bf0047na

Tags: hp, touchscreen, 23.10

I have tried installing Ubuntu 23.10 as a fresh install on my newly purchased HP Envy x360 - 13-bf0047na (it is a 2-in-1 HP laptop). I cannot get the OS to see the touchscreen.

I have tried changing the session to Xorg, at the login screen, with no effect.

I have tried querying xinput and lsusb in a terminal, it appears that the OS doesn't see any touchscreen. Hence I can't try any of the other fixes mentioned on this site.
I have also tried installing Fedora and Zorin, with no greater success in detecting a touchscreen.

The touchscreen works fine in Windows 11 (I set the machine up to dual boot with linux).

Any ideas, before I simply return the laptop to HP (I have a few days in which to do this, with no penalty)?